# Java / Spring application: Tomcat suddenly not able to deploy anymore

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, tomcat7

After noticing that my web application is not running on the production server anymore, I looked inside the tomcat log (*catalina.out*):

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
Mar 26, 2018 7:53:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 26, 2018 7:53:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 4624 ms
Mar 26, 2018 7:53:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 26, 2018 7:53:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
Mar 26, 2018 7:53:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
Mar 26, 2018 7:54:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 26, 2018 7:54:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2108 ms
Mar 26, 2018 7:54:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 26, 2018 7:54:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
Mar 26, 2018 7:54:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
Mar 26, 2018 7:55:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 26, 2018 7:55:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2428 ms
Mar 26, 2018 7:55:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 26, 2018 7:55:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
Mar 26, 2018 7:55:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
Mar 26, 2018 7:56:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 26, 2018 7:56:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1873 ms
Mar 26, 2018 7:56:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 26, 2018 7:56:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
Mar 26, 2018 7:56:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
Mar 26, 2018 7:57:42 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 26, 2018 7:57:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2534 ms
Mar 26, 2018 7:57:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 26, 2018 7:57:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
Mar 26, 2018 7:57:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
```

The deploy "loop" starts with the following message:

```
Mar 26, 2018 5:00:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 26, 2018 5:00:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
```

I tried to restart Tomcat and the entire server multiple times without success.
Can you imagine what's going wrong here?

Comment: look for the error log... I forgot where tomcat redirects stderr.  catalina.out may be?

Answer (score 0):

Similar cases have been reported and the explanation was a [Memory Leak](https://home.apache.org/~markt/presentations/2010-08-05-Memory-Leaks-JavaOne-60mins.pdf).

About this warning which mentions that *PermGen* is ignored, why don't you use the correct option ? This might explain an insufficient memory leading to your problem.

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
```

If after using the correct option (`XX:MaxMetaspaceSize`) you still have this problem, try giving it more memory. Try to understand what changed then your application cannot run anymore (data has changed in the DB ? how ?). If you still to convince yourself, remove the application and start Tomcat with no webapps at all.

Answer (score 0):

Strange...
Can you run your app with other server ? Such as glassfish or jetty ? 
I know it doesn't answer your question,but if the app work with the servers mentioned above, than your tomcat is with some problem,but if not work if them, than your code have some problems.